# need a specific JS framework to support all mobile os

Tags: iphone, android, ios4, mobile-phones, cordova

I am going to transform my website to mobile phone supported. My website consists of lots of java script and ajax stuffs so looked for a specific JS framework to support all the mobile os (android,ios,windows and blackberry).I googled and found some frame works like phonegap, sencha touch,JQTouch and appcelerator titanium. Can you people help me to find out the right one which will be suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert your website to a native app on a mobile phone then you would want to use something like PhoneGap or Titanium. If you want it to run as a native app on more than just Android and iPhone then you should use PhoneGap, otherwise Titanium will also work.

If you just want to view your website in the mobile phone browser then you might be able to just leave it as it is since iOS, Android, Windows Phone 7, and RIM OS 6 all have very good browsers. Otherwise you could certainly use jQTouch or Sencha to make your site a bit more mobile friendly.